# ssh-keygen unable to verify key "unknown option -- Y"

Tags: ssh, debian, public-key, ssh-keygen, gitea

Context:
I am trying to verify my public key on a Gitea instance. Gitea provides a token for me to generate a signature; The instructions say:

```
echo -n 'TOKEN_PROVIDED' | ssh-keygen -Y sign -n gitea -f PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY
```

When I do this, ssh-keygen replies with

```
unknown option -- Y
```

I've been able to verify before on my personal computer, but it seems like ssh-keygen on the server I am logged in at has a different ssh-keygen as it seems to be missing that flag.

- Should I be using a different version of ssh-keygen?
- How else could I verify with my current ssh-keygen version?

---

Specific stack info (although I hope the answers are general enough to be applicable elsewhere):

- Debian 10

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of OpenSSH is too old.

Debian 10 appears to have version `7.9p1`, but the `-Y` argument to `ssh-keygen` (and support for signing and verification in general) didn't show up until version `8.0p1`.

Debian 10 is approraching end-of-life. One solution would be to update to a more recent release.

An alternative solution would be to use a container runtime like Docker or Podman to run a more recent version of `ssh-keygen` (e.g., the `debian:11` image includes OpenSSH `8.4p1`).

Answer (score -2):

For ssh from windows, execute this command in cmd (opened as administrative):

```
notepad ~/.ssh/
```

after that, enter tab to complete like:

```
notepad C:\Users\User\.ssh\known_hosts
```

In the opened notepad window, remove the server IP row that you are trying to connect. Save in notepad and close it. Ssh again, it will be fixed.

On Linux:

```
vim ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Same as windows.

Comment: The question is about verifying a key, not removing one.